# locating element explicitly waiting and without wait what's difference?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch, webdriverwait

The question is about selenium webdriver's explicitly wait feature which is same locating action with a timeout. Webdriver waits element to be visible or present. In my situation, I locate elements with explicit waiting and without it. When it is without the explicit wait, it founds and assigns it. But below, I also try to locate element explicitly waiting, that variable is unassigned, and in such form passes to for iteration, and my for iteration gives `UnboundLocalError`
I know that error is not selenium but python based. I can get rid of that error by using instead of `pass` y_priceNewProds = x_priceNewProds` but I need to understand why selenium webdriver cannot locate the element with wait if it already a line above found it. There must be cookies also.

code is below;

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#reading from csv file url-s
def readCSV(path_csv):
    df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
    return df

fileCSV=readCSV(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\urls.csv')
length_of_column_urls=fileCSV['linkamazon'].last_valid_index()

def create_driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.headless = True
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    # options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

    webdriver_service = Service(r'C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\AmznScrpBot\chromedriver.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

    return driver

#going to urls 1-by-1
def goToUrl_Se(driver):
    global counter
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, length_of_column_urls + 1):
        xUrl = fileCSV.iloc[i, 1]
        print(xUrl,i)
        # going to url(amazn) via Selenium WebDriver
        driver.get(xUrl)
        parse_data()
        counter+=1
    driver.quit()

#fetch-parse the data from url page
def parse_data():
    global asin, title, bookform, priceNewProd
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=20)

    try:
        #trying code snippets where locating elements occur by XPATH, in some ofthem
        #there is also WebDriver explicit wait, that element has both methods
        #with presence_of element wait method and without explicit wait method. Just trying to understand
        #why sometimes elements cannot be located on page
        y_data_index=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-index='1']")))
        print(y_data_index.text,'y_index')
        x_data_index=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-index='1']")))
        print(x_data_index.text,'x_index')
        x_titles=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[contains(@class,"a-size-medium")]')
        x_bookforms = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro s-price-instructions-style")]//div[contains(@class,"a-row a-size-base a-color-base")]//a[contains(@class,"a-size-base a-link-normal puis-medium-weight-text s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style s-link-centralized-style a-text-bold")]')
        x_priceNewProds = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"a-row a-size-base a-color-base")]//span[contains(@data-a-color,"base")]//span[contains(@class,"a-offscreen")][1]')
        y_priceNewProds=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"a-row a-size-base a-color-base")]//span[contains(@data-a-color,"base")]//span[contains(@class,"a-offscreen")][1]')))
    except:
        pass

    for i in range(len(x_titles)):
        x_title=x_titles[i].text
        x_priceNewProd = x_priceNewProds[i].text
        print(x_priceNewProd)
        y_priceNewProd=y_priceNewProds[i].text
        print(y_priceNewProd)
        try:
            x_bookform=x_bookforms[i].text
            print(x_bookform)
        except:
            x_bookform='-'
        title = x_title
        bookform = x_bookform
        priceNewProd = x_priceNewProd
        write_to_csv()

def write_to_csv():
    if counter==0:
        df=pd.DataFrame({'Products':title,'Bookform':bookform,'Price':priceNewProd},index=[0])
        wr=df.to_csv('results_new00.csv',index=False,mode='w')
    else:
        df=pd.DataFrame({'Products':title,'Bookform':bookform,'Price':priceNewProd},index=[0])
        wr=df.to_csv('results_new00.csv',index=False,mode='a',header=False)

driver=create_driver()
goToUrl_Se(driver)
```

`y_priceNewProd=y_priceNewProds[i].text UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y_priceNewProds' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't share all the code including the link we can't know what exactly happens there, but I guess that this line

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"a-row a-size-base a-color-base")]//span[contains(@data-a-color,"base")]//span[contains(@class,"a-offscreen")][1]')))
```

Throws exception since that element(s) are / is not visible.
This is why `y_priceNewProds` remains not assigned any value.
While if you use simple `driver.find_elements` method it can find those elements since they are existing but, again, not visible.
**UPD**
After you shared the link I tested that and now I can say: Yes, I was right!
Those elements are not visible.
The following code throws `TimeoutException`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&fs=true&ds=v1%3AgAO0%2BZc%2BC6RthRkqyWzOHmDVufv7JbuCK96Grvjle68&qid=1665559431&rnid=8622845011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_5'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

m_list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"a-row a-size-base a-color-base")]//span[contains(@data-a-color,"base")]//span[contains(@class,"a-offscreen")][1]')))
print(m_list)
```

**UPD2**
But if you will take the direct parent of that element it will work correctly since it is visible.
For the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&fs=true&ds=v1%3AgAO0%2BZc%2BC6RthRkqyWzOHmDVufv7JbuCK96Grvjle68&qid=1665559431&rnid=8622845011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_5'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

m_list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"a-row a-size-base a-color-base")]//span[contains(@data-a-color,"base")]')))
print(len(m_list))
```

the output is:

```
27
```

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&fs=true&qid=1665559431&rnid=8622845011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_5&ds=v1%3AgAO0%2BZc%2BC6RthRkqyWzOHmDVufv7JbuCK96Grvjle68

Comment: I have added all code, and link as a comment. It means if I will use `presence of element` instead of ` visibility of element` it will not throw an error

Comment: Right, elements are present, but not visible

Comment: strange in anyways. If I can locate it without explicit wait, then why I need explicit waiting. And paradoxically it founds element but it is not visible?

Comment: Not all the elements are visible. If you take the direct parent of element you tried to work with you will see they are visible. See the updated answer.

Comment: yes, tehre 27 webelements in that case. If it gives 27 as a number why giving an error about visibuility? issues with AJAX, loading asynchronously page?

Comment: No, it's just because not all the elements are visible. I have no better explanations about that. Still have things to learn about :) The code is waiting 20-30 seconds and only then throws the exception. It's not about asynchronously loading. In case even 1 element matching that locator was visible there was no exception thrown since the code is waiting for at least 1 element with given locator matching the defined expected conditions. So, no visible elements were found until timeout exception was thrown

Comment: please, look for what it, i will open a new question. I think better to ask for solution that philosophy of why that happens. I will post question immediately. Thanks for comment about AJAX

Comment: there is a good explanation of topic that explicit waits are performed on local machine but implicit waits in remote server. Maybe the reason is there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxgL2L1cZRI

Comment: at your free time, could you also look at my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74254409/element-present-but-does-not-give-text-value-of-span-tag please

Comment: I saw that post, but since, as I said here, I can't give more explanations I didn't answer there

Comment: There question is different, I just cannot take the value of span tag. Even though it finds all elements

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll try later in case the question will stay unanswered

Comment: Will not do it now, maybe tomorrow, but what is your goal there, what are you trying to achieve? I see x_price, y_price, z_price, a_price... a strange mix, each of them pointing to other elements. But again, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: nope, they are pointing to the same element just price tag of product. I achieved the result in different way, taking two different span tags. Now, I will try to take price tag of clas 'a-off

Comment: So, that issue is resolved?

Comment: Ahaha)) It is really strange you need to give alook. I tried another way. `newVAR_prices_xpath_parchild=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[contains(text(),"Paperback")]//parent::div/following-sibling::div/a/span[1]/span[contains(@class,"a-offscreen")]')` 16 webelements clearly shows on inspect mode. but cannot get text  of them? I am trying to doubt if `webelement.text` is right method :))

Comment: it took all my day. I get at the end what I need. But why span tag with class 'a-offscreen' is just strange to me I need to investigate

Comment: I saw there '::before' I serched internet about pseudo elements and webdrivers does not give you value of them I tried using `newVAR_price_xpath_parchild = newVAR_prices_xpath_parchild[i].value_of_css_property(':before')` no effect but also not an error. I hink i got the problem till morning I wish to solve it

Comment: impossible to get css pseudo element by webdriver citation ""::after is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is, and would essentiallly be like this"" from https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/ZUi9cenA13o

Comment: Pseudo elements not supported by XPath 1.0. So, to work with them you will need CSS Selectors and JavaScripts. I read all your comments here but couldn't understand you clearly, I'm sorry